# Register provider whose interface has a mandatory constructor argument

Tags: nestjs

Want to register a provider who is implementing the following Interface:

```
export interface FooBar {
  new(name: string);
}
```

The fact, that the interface requires a constructor argument does not allow me to register it as provider within a module.

Tried to find a way around by not registering it with the module and just adding the 'Injectable' and the Inject for property injection without success.

Anyone stumbled upon this before ?

Comment: Should the required string be injected by the application container? Where does `name` come from? Is it static in the context of your application?

Comment: Its a OIDC library, where 'name' represents the model (entity) name. Its not static. 
Want to embed it into my NestJS application without losing DI and the Application-Context.

Comment: nest.js does not offer dynamic providers out of the box. It might be possible to find a more complex setup, e.g., with a set of providers, but you need to give more context in your question. For the abstract example you have given, I would say it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't use interfaces in typescript to work with DI, because after transportation they will be completely gone. You can use abstract classes for that and it works!